# How to add legend to plot with multiple lines using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, this is the data that I have:

```
x <- seq(-5, 5, length=1000)
y1 <- dnorm(x, 0, 0.2)
y2 <- dnorm(x, 0, 1)

data1 <- data.frame(x, y1, y2)
```

I generate a graph with an example of the distribution of two variables, and I generate the graph like so:

```
p <- data1 %>% ggplot()
p + geom_line(aes(x, y1), linetype = 2) + geom_line(aes(x, y2)) + geom_line(aes(x, y= 0)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = -0.05, label = "Party A"), nudge_x = 0.5) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = -0.05, label = "Party B"), nudge_x = - 0.5) +
  xlab("Ideological scale: Left to Right") +  
  ylab("Prabability")
```

I am trying to add the legend showing that the dashed line is the distribution of party A and the solid line is the distribution of party B. How can I add the legend?

Comment: `data. Frame` is a parsing error, are you able to run your sample code?

Comment: yeap, my code is running fine. Not sure whats the error about, the code is very straight forward

Comment: oh i see whats the problem.

Comment: It was the automatic spell-checker

Comment: It's a problem when you provide code (sample as it may be) that you want us to fix or work with, and you've never run it yourself. I understand you're in a pinch and want to resolve your issue here, but when we are slaloming between "typo bugs" that are not an issue for you, it's not high-confidence that the problems we find are really the problem you need us to find.

Comment: I did run the code myself and it was fine. The automatic spell-checker changed it when I typed it the first time. I already edited it as soon as you pointed out the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot2` really prefers "long data". I'll use `tidyr::pivot_longer` here (as well as `dplyr` for some massaging) to convert from wide to long, but it can also easily be done with `data.table` or (with a touch more work) base R.

A quick demo of wide-to-long:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
pivot_longer(data1, -x, names_to = "y", values_to = "val") |>
  mutate(lbl = if_else(y == "y1", "Party A", "Party B"))
# # A tibble: 2,000 × 4
#        x y           val lbl    
#    <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>  
#  1 -5    y1    3.83e-136 Party A
#  2 -5    y2    1.49e-  6 Party B
#  3 -4.99 y1    1.34e-135 Party A
#  4 -4.99 y2    1.56e-  6 Party B
#  5 -4.98 y1    4.65e-135 Party A
#  6 -4.98 y2    1.64e-  6 Party B
#  7 -4.97 y1    1.62e-134 Party A
#  8 -4.97 y2    1.73e-  6 Party B
#  9 -4.96 y1    5.59e-134 Party A
# 10 -4.96 y2    1.81e-  6 Party B
# # ℹ 1,990 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

This allows us to have simpler `geom_*` calls, typically down to a single. I'll also infer that we can replace your `geom_line(aes(x, y=0))` to `geom_hline`, in order to add the horizontal line.

```r
library(ggplot2)
pivot_longer(data1, -x, names_to = "y", values_to = "val") |>
  mutate(lbl = if_else(y == "y1", "Party A", "Party B")) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, val)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = y, linetype = lbl)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = lbl),
    data = ~ filter(., val > max(val)/2, .by = y) %>% slice_head(n = 1, by = lbl),
    hjust = 1.2
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Party A"=2, "Party B"=1))
```

[image: ggplot2 with labels and legend]

I also add the label programmatically by updating the `data=` inside the `geom_text` call, using the `~`-style "function" expression.